# Solve Non-Linear First-Order ODE for Parabola Focus point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I'd like to know how to solve this **Non-Linear First-Order ODE**, step-by-step:
$$
\frac{2y'}{{y'}^2-1} = \frac{x}{y-D}
$$
where $y=f(x)$ and $D$ is a constant.

Wolfram Alpha gives solution, but hides step-by-step guide: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*f%27%28x%29%2F%281-%28f%27%28x%29%29%5E2%29%3Dx%2F%28D-f%28x%29%29

It also states that it's a **D'Alembert's equation**, but when I tried to research how to solve it, Google was overwhelmed with the **D'Alembert's wave equation** instead.

Long story:

> I was trying to solve, which function reflects incoming parallel rays of light to a single point. I know it is a parabola, but wanted to prove it myself. The train of thoughts I had:
>
> Out of geometric reasoning and from the reflection of rays one can deduce the followings (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh2j1.png)):
>
> $\frac{x}{y-D}=\tan(\pi-2\alpha)=-\tan(2\alpha)=-\frac{2\tan(\alpha)}{1-\tan^2(\alpha)}=\frac{2y'}{{y'}^2-1}$
>
> And this is where I'm stuck. If anyone has a better method to prove this property, all suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I’ll point you in a direction that might work. First, use the quadratic formula for  $y’$. Then, substitute the inside of the square root. $(y-D)^2 +x^2=u^2$. After another substitution like $u=vx$, you should get a separable DE.

Comment: @Tavish Nice, thank you :) Do you have any recommendation on how to guess what the appropriate substitutions are, to get separable DEs? Is there any resource on web i can learn from?

Comment: I’m not very experienced at these, so I’m afraid I cannot recommend any resources. But basically I saw a square root and I tried to remove it by letting the inside be a square. Another thing, if the DE can be written entirely in terms of, say, $\frac yx$, then it’s a good idea to substitute for $\frac yx$. I’m sure there lots more techniques out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{2y'}{{y'}^2-1} = \frac{x}{y-D}$$
Substitute $u=x^2$:
$$\frac{4xy'}{4x^2{y'}^2-1} = \frac{x}{y-D}$$
$$\frac{4y'}{4u{y'}^2-1} = \frac{1}{y-D}$$
$$y-D=\frac{4u{y'}^2-1}{4y'}$$
$$y=u{y'}-\dfrac 1{4y'}+D$$
This is [Clairaut's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation)
$$y=uy'+f(y')$$
To find the general solution just set $y'=C$ in the differential equation and substitute back $u=x^2$:
$$y=u{y'}-\dfrac 1{4y'}+D$$
$$y(u)=u{C}-\dfrac 1{4C}+D$$
$$\boxed{y(x)=x^2C-\dfrac 1{4C}+D}$$

Answer (score 2):

Replacing $y = f(x)$ and cross multiplying, we get
$$\begin{aligned}
2 f'(x) (f(x) - D) &= x(f''(x)-1) \\
0 &= xf''(x) - 2f'(x)(f(x)-D)) -x
\end{aligned}$$
Let $f'(x) = a$, then this is quadratic in $a$, and solving for the roots of $a$ gives us,
$$\begin{aligned}
f'(x) &= \frac{2 (f(x)-D) \pm \sqrt{4(f(x)-D)^2 + 4x^2}}{2x} \\
f'(x) &= \frac{f(x) - D}{x} \pm \sqrt{\frac{f(x)-D}{x}+1}
\end{aligned}$$
Let $\frac{f(x)-D}{x} = u$. Then $f(x)-D = xu, \partial f(x) = u\partial{x} + x\partial{u}, \ \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = u + x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$

$$\begin{aligned}
u + x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &= u + \sqrt{u^2+1} \\
 x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &= \sqrt{u^2+1} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\sqrt{u^2+1}} &=  \frac{\partial x}{x}
\end{aligned}$$
Integrating on both sides gives us,
$$\begin{aligned}
\sinh^{-1}u &= \ln{x} + c \\
\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{f(x)-D}{x}\right) &= \ln{x} + c \\ e^{\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{f(x)-D}{x}\right)} + c &= x \\
x\sinh{(\ln x+c)}+D &= f(x)
\end{aligned}$$